# Query for maintaining stock of product

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am trying to create a stock query to maintain stock of my product. The following image shows my table structure and what I have tried.[image]

My query result in this image which is not what I'm trying to get:

[image]

What I am trying to do is:

(1) The quantity of particular product I have purchased?

(2) The quantity of particular product I have sold?

(3) The quantity of particular product I have in my hand (in stock)?

What am I doing wrong?

[DOWNLOAD MS ACCESS FILE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4VKVJp2vo33ZXV0RkNTeWZRWjQ/view?usp=sharing)

My query:

```
SELECT Product.ProductName,
       Sum([Purchase Order Detail].Quantity) AS [Purchase Quantity],
       Sum([Order Detail].Quantity) AS [Sales Quantity]
FROM ([Purchase Order Detail]
   RIGHT JOIN Product ON [Purchase Order Detail].ProductID = Product.ProductID)
   LEFT JOIN [Order Detail] ON Product.ProductID = [Order Detail].ProductID
GROUP BY Product.ProductName;
```

Comment: Can u paste ur query, that u've tried in Question! that will give better idea

Comment: currently what are you getting under `Purchase Quantity` column... Is it amount or quantity?

Comment: Mixing RIGHT and LEFT joins.. That's very hard to understand. I recommend using only LEFT joins, because most people find them much easier to understand.

Comment: I am getting quantity but it is much larger than expected. i have attached link for download access file please see updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot join purchased and order tables together because you will end up hitting more matching records than you actually want to see. Hence your sum is incorrect in your previous query.

You can use sub-queries to get your result. something like this:

```
SELECT
    Product.ProductID, 
    Product.ProductName, 
    (select sum(quantity) from [purchase order detail] where [purchase order detail].[ProductID] = product.productid) AS Purchased_quantity,
    (select sum(quantity) from [order detail] where [order detail].[ProductID] = product.productid) AS Sold_quantity,
    (select sum(quantity) from [purchase order detail] where [purchase order detail].[ProductID] = product.productid) - (select sum(quantity) from [order detail] where [order detail].[ProductID] = product.productid) AS Stock
FROM Product
ORDER BY Product.ProductName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your Query that will give desired output:

```
SELECT [Product].ProductName
    ,SUM([Purchase Order Detail].Quantity) AS [Purchase Quantity]
    ,[Order Detail].Quantity AS [Sales Quantity]
FROM [Product]
LEFT JOIN [Purchase Order Detail] ON [Product].ProductID = [Purchase Order Detail].ProductID 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(Quantity)as Quantity
                ,[Order Detail].ProductID 
            FROM [Order Detail]
            GROUP BY [Order Detail].ProductID
        )AS [Order Detail] ON [Product].ProductID = [Order Detail].ProductID
GROUP BY [Product].ProductName,[Order Detail].Quantity
```